# Clear Application Event Log by Source

Tags: powershell, event-log

I've seen various sources suggesting something like this to clear *all* event logs:

```
wevtutil el | Foreach-Object {Write-Host "Clearing $_"; wevtutil cl "$_"}
```

But what I would like to do is remove from the application log only those events that have a particular source (a windows service that I had created). Is that possible? I know something like:

```
wevtutil gl application
```

Gives you information about the log, but is there a way to get the events in that log and remove ones that match?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows does not allow removing individual entries from Event logs; it's either clear a log of all entries, or remove a (non-native) log completely.

So in a nutshell you can't; it's a system log, allowing removal of individual entries would be considered unsafe.

If you wrote the service, modify it to use the Event Log the way you require, instead of trying to bend the Event Log to your service.

For more info, here's the same question on ServerFault:

- [How can I remove specific events from the event log in Windows Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8339/how-can-i-remove-specific-events-from-the-event-log-in-windows-server-2008)